# Linking oAuth Providers in Firebase iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication

I'm new to Firebase and iOS and I was wondering if someone knew how to link multiple oAuth Providers. I followed the Firebase docs and tried to implement this function:

```
func firebaseSignInWithLink(credential: FIRAuthCredential) {

        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
            if error != nil {
                debugPrint("APP: there has been an error signing into firebase, perhaps another account with same email")
                debugPrint("APP: \(error)")

                // if existing email, try linking
                FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.link(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        debugPrint("APP: there has been an error signing into firebase")
                        debugPrint("APP: \(error)")
                    }
                    else {
                        debugPrint("APP: successfully signed into firebase")
                    }
                })
            }
            else {
                debugPrint("APP: successfully signed into firebase")
            }
        })
    }
```

The `FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.link` function never gets called despite the above `debugPrint("APP: \(error)")` being called. Because this doesn't work, I keep getting the error below:

> Optional(Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17007 \"The email address is already in use by another account.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The email address is already in use by another account., error_name=ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE, FIRAuthErrorUserInfoEmailKey=example@gmail.com})"

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you :D

Comment: I'm working on the same problem.  I haven't mastered it yet but if you already have "currentUser" (which I'm pretty certain you do), you should not call sign-in because that users email was already associated with a DIFFERENT IDP on a prior login....hence the error we see...

Comment: I think the thing that confused me was how we can get the currentUser object if the user can't login via the oAuth that produced the error. Does the user have to try all possible auth methods until he/she successfully logs in and gets the currentUser object, and then has to sign in to oAuth again to link them? :/

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are confused by the instructions. On firebase documentation it reads

To link auth provider credentials to an existing user account:

1. Sign in the user using any authentication provider or method.
2. Complete the sign-in flow for the new authentication provider **up to, but not including, calling one of the FIRAuth.signInWith methods**. For example, get the user's Google ID token, Facebook access token, or email and password.
3. Get a FIRAuthCredential for the new authentication provider

So you should not call the method FIRAuth.signInWith. I should also point out that you want to create a link to an existing account, so you should have signed in first and then you can link it. This is why you should have a currentUser.

Answer (score 0):

It occurred because of unchecking "Multiple accounts per email address setting firebase setting" from firebase console.

[image]

Comment: This will setup a new UID in auth though... so multiple accounts will exist, not just one account with multiple providers. This may cause issues if you need persistence using a unique UID for a single user from multiple providers